# IF, AND, OR functions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm looking to build a formula with the following conditions:

- Sales >= 70%
- Bills >= 32%
- Accounts >= 43%
  Meeting all the above criteria would result in "Pass" appearing as the text.

Built within that same formula, I'm hoping to also set the following conditions:

- Sales >= 70%
- Bills < 32% OR Accounts < 43%
  Meeting these criteria would result in "Review"

If Sales criteria is not met, the text should return as "Doesn't Pass"

This is how far I've gotten with the first set of criteria but I'm not sure how to incorporate the second criteria if Bills or Accounts would be lower than the set targets into the same formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=70%,A3>=32%,A4>=43%,"Pass","Doesn't Pass"))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

- try nesting like this:

  ```
  =IF(AND(A2>=70%,
          A3>=32%,
          A4>=43%), "Pass", IF(AND(A2>=70%, 
                                   OR(A3<32%, 
                                      A4<43%)), "Review", "Doesn't Pass"))
  ```